# TinyMCE image float, automatic set margin

Tags: 7, theming, wysiwyg

I'm using TinyMCE as WYSIWYG editor. When I set the floating of an image to "left" or "right", I want to set a right- of left-margin with CSS automatically. So the images has only a gap between img and text.

When I just add a margin to the IMG, there's a at all sides...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `styles` WYSIWYG button shows `image right` or `image left` try applying that and save your edit. If that applies ok you can use Firebug to see the CSS class it adds to the image and just alter the css rules to your needs.

Or else, you can supply your own css styles to a wysiwyg profile. They are typically of the form:

`wysiwyg_option_name=css_class_name`

for example:

`ImageRight=img-right`

you then make an image right class in your themes css file:

`.img-right { padding: 0 0 5px 5px; }`

I believe both TinyMCE and/or the WYSIWYG module both support these features.